# Нажатие колесика/кнопок мыши в консоли С++

Tags: c++, windows, консоль

Как можно обработать:

- нажатие колёсика мыши
- нажатие кнопок на мышке

на какой-то символ в консоли Windows?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events

Comment: Комментарий выше все еще актуален. Что вы пробовали, какие трудности возникли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите реализовать нажатие на колесико мыши в консоли, нажатие на правую кнопку или левую, а также узнать координаты, вам нужно:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE hin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // получаем дескриптор
    INPUT_RECORD InputRecord; // используется для возвращения информации о входных сообщениях в консольном входном буфере
    DWORD Events; // unsigned long
    COORD coord; // для координат X, Y

    /*Запретить выделение консоли*/
    DWORD prev_mode;
    GetConsoleMode(hin, &prev_mode);
    SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | (prev_mode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE));

    SetConsoleMode(hin, ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT); // разрешаем обработку мыши

    while (true) 
    {
        ReadConsoleInput(hin, &InputRecord, 1, &Events); // считывание 

        if (InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == MOUSE_WHEELED) // нажато колесико
        {
            coord.X = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
            coord.Y = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
            cout << "Kolesiko nazhato - X" << coord.X << ", Y = " << coord.Y << endl;
        }
        else if (InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == RIGHTMOST_BUTTON_PRESSED) // правая кнопка
        {
            coord.X = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
            coord.Y = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
            cout << "right - X" << coord.X << ", Y = " << coord.Y << endl;
        }
        else if (InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED) // левая кнопка
        {
            coord.X = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
            coord.Y = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
            cout << "left - X" << coord.X << ", Y = " << coord.Y << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```